# How to start Weblogic admin server

Tags: wlst

when I am starting WebLogic admin server with local host:port no/console I am getting the following error:

> Console/Management requests or requests with <require-admin-traffic> specified to 'true' can only be made through an administration channel.

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manualy change your config.xml, find the `<require-admin-traffic>` element and change it's value to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the option administration-port-enabled is set to true in config.xml
(available under ../MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/config)

```
<administration-port-enabled>false</administration-port-enabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect. Or you can use the administration port you entered when configuring the server to use the admin server, which will be different from the default one. The default one 7001, the default for the admin server is 9002 and you can only access it via https.
Not downvoting the answer as it is accepted and maybe useful for users which can't recover their admin port, but this is obviously not best practise.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open config.xml under the folder ../config,
change this row from '*true'* to *'false'*:
true

It should then be ok.

Skender Kollcaku

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably trying to use the administration console on the application port.  You need the administration port.

- Go to your domain directories (ex. /opt/weblogic/domains/mydomain)
- Go into sub-directory config
- Run `grep "administration-port" config.xml`
- This will give you a port number, like:  `<administration-port>12345</administration-port>`
- Use that port to connect to `/console/`.
- ex: `https://YOUR-SERVER:12345/console/`

This is much preferable to using the application port for the console, like @Peter pointed out.